# glCallList with slick-util

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Whenever I draw my display list my slick util text wont render properly.

While using glCallList:

[image]

Without using glCallList:

[image]

Rendering the display list:

```
    if (dlLocation != -1) {
        GL11.glPushMatrix();

        GL11.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
        GL11.glCallList(dlLocation);

        GL11.glPopMatrix();
    }
```

All of the display lists are created with this method:

```
private static int createDisplayList(Texture t, int width, int height) {
    int returnInt = glGenLists(1);

    glNewList(returnInt, GL_COMPILE);
    {
        t.bind();
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2f(0, 0);

            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex2f(width, 0);

            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex2f(width, height);

            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex2f(0, height);
        }
        glEnd();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    glEndList();

    return returnInt;
}
```

I'm rendering the text using slick-util's TrueTypeFont.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing **`glBindTexture`** ( in your case `t.bind()` ) outside of **`glNewList`** might help.

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
glCallList(newList)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
```

Comment: Well when im Binding the texture this way how does it know where to put the texture? Sense there is no glTextureCoord? Sorry im new with openGl dont really know much outside of imitate mode :-)

Comment: Accually never mind i just dont do t.bind() within the displaylist create method?

Comment: Actually help me out here. With glBindTexture the texture is an integer. How would i go about using this with Slick-Util?

Comment: Not much of a Slick user, but seems like you're doing it right. To bind a texture - `texture.bind();` and to unbind -
`TextureImpl.bindNone();`

Comment: @Iggy: Please rephrase your answer, that the display list creation code lacked the binding of the texture. Because display lists are perfectly capable of storing that. In fact waaay back with OpenGL-1.0 when there were no texture *objects* but a glTexImage function, display lists were ab-/used as texture storage, by putting the call to glTexImage inside a display list.

Comment: @datenwolf Display list creation code lacked texture binding features in versions **1.x** or just **1.0**? Because even here Kuliu is using **GL11(1.1)**. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I agree with @datenwolf. Can you please provide a source for the claim in this answer? I even went back to old spec documents, and found nothing suggesting that `glBindTexture()` cannot be executed as part of a display list.

Comment: Interesting. This is a claim from previous experience and things I've heard others say. But indeed documentation does not say anything about it. Thanks @RetoKoradi.

Comment: @Iggy: Binding textures in display lists works just fine. I think the people who struggled doing it were by accident putting the glBindTexture call within a glBegin/glEnd block which never was legal. Texture binding is a feature that got introduced only with OpenGL-1.1. Before that there was no texture binding at all, and instead you'd call glTexImage within a display list to somehow get the same effect (the `wglShareLists` function is named due to that).